# Disabling Copy/Paste action from the Tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I disable the copying and pasting on the tkinter entry field. I tried using:

```
self.ent_city = Tkinter.Entry(bd='4',width='32', state='readonly')
```

But this command is nearly similar to `state = 'disabled'` . I want to disable Copy/paste or Cut/Paste on my entry widget.

Any help would be appreciated.!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's impossible with an `Entry` widget, as the whole point of an `Entry` widget is that you type something into it- therefore it is impossible to localise no cutting/copying/pasting to that widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind key-presses and the right-button click like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.ent = Entry(self, width=15)
        self.ent.pack()

        self.ent.bind('<Control-x>', lambda e: 'break') #disable cut
        self.ent.bind('<Control-c>', lambda e: 'break') #disable copy
        self.ent.bind('<Control-v>', lambda e: 'break') #disable paste
        self.ent.bind('<Button-3>', lambda e: 'break')  #disable right-click

root = Tk()
app = App()
mainloop()
```

It's not fool-proof, but I think it's a decent solution. Check http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm for more info.

Comment: This is not good programming practice.  It is simple another hack to try to solve a problem.

Comment: @Anonymous Care to elaborate?

Comment: This simply disables certain keyboard combinations and right-clicking. This does not take into account modified keyboard shortcuts, swapping mouse buttons and many other ways to use copy-and-paste. A better way to do this might be to block all forms of entering text into the entry except for printable characters (letters, digits, common symbols such as ! and @ and backspace) to eliminate all methods of copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an official way to disable cut/copy/paste in tkinter (very annoying), and calling `self.ent.bind('<Control-v>', lambda e:'break')` doesn't seem to work on XWayland (tkinter runs in x11 on Xorg, or XWayland on Wayland)
I've tried `self.ent.unbind('<<paste>>')` but this is no help either.

A bodge that seems to work is to bind your own function to paste, in it, empty the clipboard into a string, then fill it again after a 20ms timeout, this way, when tkinter pastes, it pastes nothing. This isn't ideal though as any image or html on the clipboard will get mushed up. Also, you have to catch the error if the clipboard is empty.

```
self.ent.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)
def paste(self, event):
    try: s = self.ent.clipboard_get()
    except: s = ''
    self.ent.clipboard_clear()
    #any other code you want to run on paste here
    self.ent.after(20, lambda: self.ent.clipboard_append(s))
```